# Merging multiple long data frames into one

Tags: r, merge

I have converted my wide data to 5 different long-form data frames. However, now I cannot figure out how to put all 5 into one long-form data frame.

I used the following code to break down the wide data into long:

```
data_longH <- melt(data, id.vars = c("X", "Y", "Z"),
               measure.vars = c("R", "A", "G"), 
               variable.name="Type", value.name="name")
```

this data frame has 1500 observations.

When i try to merge it with another data frame that has 1500 observations, I get a new dataset that has all the variables I want but also 335000 observations.

```
d1 <- merge(data_longH, data_longU, by = c("X", "Y", "Z"))
```

At some point, when i merge 4 of the datasets using this formula, I stop seeing all the variables I want and the observations keep increasing.

My goal is to merge 5 datasets and have 10 variables with 1500 observations only.

Comment: try using unique() function on merged data set.. or else provide a example of your data